# Java concurrent modification using fork/join

Tags: java

While building the compute function for my fork/join I got the error concurrent modification using fork/join. I know this has to do with the concurrent modification of the structure you are looping though. However, I don't see where this is the case in my code(hmap is a regular hashmap here as a class variable):

```
public void compute() {
        if (left < right) {
            int mid = (left + right) / 2;
            CHTcounter leftSort = new CHTcounter(array, left, mid,hmap);
            CHTcounter rightSort = new CHTcounter(array, mid + 1, right,hmap);
            leftSort.fork();
            rightSort.compute();
            leftSort.join();

            leftSort.hmap.entrySet()
                        .forEach(entry -> rightSort.hmap.merge(
                                entry.getKey(),
                                entry.getValue(),
                                (key, value) -> entry.getValue() + value));
                hmap = rightSort.hmap;
        }else{
            array[left].getUsers().forEach((el) -> {
                    hmap.put(el,1);
                });
        }
    }
```

The error has to do with the for each in the if code block but from my understanding I am not changing the data structure I am looping over. Can someone help me understand why this is still concurrent modification?

Comment: I'm guessing `leftSort` is not actually independent of the underlying `hmap` and *does* modify it, just where we can't see it.  We'd need to see the implementation of `CHTcounter`

Comment: In particular, `rightSort.hmap.merge()` looks suspicious.

Comment: Is `merge()` the method from a standard HashMap?  Note this from the documentation: *This method will, on a best-effort basis, throw a ConcurrentModificationException if it is detected that the remapping function modifies this map during computation.*

Comment: Yes, the merge is the standard merge operation of the hashmap. But I just do an addition on 2 numbers during the merge so this isn't a remapping normally right?